# How to remove or reduce space for hand-written signature in `closing` of `letter` documenty class?

Tags: spacing, letters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to type specifically on this part of the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68493/how-to-type-specifically-on-this-part-of-the-page)

In `letter` documentclass closing generates space for hand-written signature:

```
Best regards,




John Doe
```

How to remove or reduce this space:

```
Best regards,
John Doe
```

?

Answer (score 3):

I followed advice I've found on http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-latex-letter-document-class.html about modifying length of `\medskipamount` :

```
\addtolength{\medskipamount}{-1\medskipamount}
\closing{Best regards,}
```

I don't know about side-effects of this code and, how `clear` it is.
For me - it worked.

Comment: This may have many adverse effects; have a look at the answer I linked before.

Comment: Use e.g. `\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{.5\baselineskip}` as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308204/koma-script-scrartclscrletter-adjust-spacing-of-signature-with-includegrap). `sigbeforeevskip` is the proper length as you can see in the graphic [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109797/how-to-remove-space-between-back-address-and-address-in-scrlttr2)