# How to remove space between back address and address in scrlttr2?

Tags: spacing, koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

There is a blank line between the back address and the address? How can I remove it?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ngerman,    ae}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} % Deutsche Gänsefüßchen

\KOMAoptions{backaddress=true} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{<Name back address>}      
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{<street back address>\\ <town back address>}

\begin{document}
 \begin{letter}{name\\ street\\ town}       
  \opening{Hello}
  some text
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [document class `scrlttr2`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) doesn't use normal length adjusting there contents. Instead it uses pseudolengths. The most important length are described in [scrguien](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) or the German version [scrguide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf). Both documentations have a great picture which are showing the pseudolengths. To explain my solution here the picture:

[image]

In your case you must change the height `toaddrheight` because the complete return address and adress are putted in one vertical box with the specific height. The distance is done be `\vfil`. So to reduce the distance between return address and adress you must reduce the pseudolength `toaddrheight`. Related to the documentation this is done by:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@tempskipa}{-2cm}%
\@addtoplength{toaddrheight}{\@tempskipa}
\makeatother
```

If I add this lines to your example I get the following result:

[image]

Here the example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrlttr2} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
%\usepackage{ngerman,    ae}%veraltet
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} % Deutsche Gänsefüßchen

\KOMAoptions{backaddress=true} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{<Name back address>}      
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{<street back address>\\ <town back address>}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@tempskipa}{-2cm}%
\@addtoplength{toaddrheight}{\@tempskipa}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 \begin{letter}{name\\ street\\ town}       
  \opening{Hello}
  some text
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

*Note* The packages `ngerman` and `ae` are obsolete. Use `babel` with the specific language `ngerman`.

The difficult setting of such lengths are basing on the simple statement: Normally a user doesn't need to change any length.

Comment: Note that nowadays, changing the length would be done that way `\addtoplength[-]{toaddrheight}{2cm}` without the requirement to change @ behaviour or to define a temporary variable.

Answer (score 7):

Since KOMA-Script Version 3.17 you can use:

```
\KOMAoptions{addrfield=topaligned}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoptions{addrfield=topaligned}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Name back address}      
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{street back address\\ town back address}
\begin{document}
 \begin{letter}{name\\ street\\ town}       
  \opening{Hello}
  some text
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

Update regarding the comments:

If there should be a bit more space below the `backaddress`, you can use `\setkomavar{specialmail}{\mbox{}}` as suggested by Rasmus in a comment below. Then the result would be

[image]

If this space should be enlarged, you can use `\setkomavar{specialmail}{\strut}`. To change the size of the strut, change the settings of the font element `specialmail`, eg: `\addtokomafont{specialmail}{\Huge}`. Alternativly an invisible rule can be used,eg: `\setkomavar{specialmail}{\rule{0pt}{5mm}}`

Comment: If one wants a bit more space between the `backaddress` and the 'proper' address, one can use `\setkomavar{specialmail}{\mbox{}}`

Comment: @Rasmus That’s great. Any way to expand that vertical space even further? It seems the “specialmail” is either empty and invisible or has a fixed height which cannot be changed.

Comment: @caw See my updated answer.

Comment: @esdd Thanks a lot, that works perfectly. Any reason why `\rule{0mm}{25mm}` works while `\vspace{25mm}` does not?