# KOMA-Script margin between text and bottom

Tags: margins, koma-script, scrlttr2

I want to reduce the space between the text and the bottom of the page from the following working example. So that I can add more text to the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}   
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoptions{%
    pagenumber=false,
    parskip=full,
    fontsize=11pt,
    firstfoot=false,
    fromalign=right,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true,
    fromrule=false,
    foldmarks=false
}

\newcommand{\myFirstname}{John}
\newcommand{\myFamilyname}{Doe}
\newcommand{\myStreet}{3500 West Olive Avenue}
\newcommand{\myTown}{Burbank, CA 91505-5512}


\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{signature}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\myStreet\\\myTown}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname, \myStreet , \myTown}
\setkomavar{place}{Burbank}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone\,]{(01\,23)\,45\,67\,89\,10}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter\,]{john.doe@email.de}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}




\setkomavar{subject}{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{letter}{Richard M Winsor\\
2192 Lawman Avenue\\ 
Arlington\\
22204 Virginia
}
%
\opening{Dear Mr Winsor,}
%
\blindtext[1]
\noindent \blindtext[4]


\closing{\raggedright Yours sincerely,}
\enlargethispage{6\baselineskip}
\medskip
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The relevant length are shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109797/how-to-remove-space-between-back-address-and-address-in-scrlttr2/109855#109855

Comment: @Bobyandbob: Your links are not working here. The op uses the class scrlttr2.

Comment: Use option `enlargefirstpage` as described in section 4.10 of the English KOMA-Script manual [`scrguien.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.html). Or move your `\enlargethispage` behind `\opening`, before `\blindtext[1]`. If you want more text on the second etc. page, use either `DIV` or the `geometry` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I recommend to set as many options as possible already at `\documentclass`. At least `fontsize` and `parskip` should be used before the class loads `typearea` and the `lco`-file.

Second step would be to try option `enlargefirstpage` (see KOMA-Script manual, section 4.10 for more information). This will enlarge the text area of the first page despite the type area calculated by `typearea` down to `\footskip` above the position of `firstfootvpos`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
    pagenumber=false,
    parskip=full,
    fontsize=11pt,
    firstfoot=false,
    fromalign=right,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true,
    fromrule=false,
    foldmarks=false,
    enlargefirstpage,
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marvosym}   
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\myFirstname}{John}
\newcommand{\myFamilyname}{Doe}
\newcommand{\myStreet}{3500 West Olive Avenue}
\newcommand{\myTown}{Burbank, CA 91505-5512}


\setkomavar{date}{\today} 
\setkomavar{fromname}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{signature}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\myStreet\\\myTown}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{\myFirstname\ \myFamilyname, \myStreet , \myTown}
\setkomavar{place}{Burbank}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone\,]{(01\,23)\,45\,67\,89\,10}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter\,]{john.doe@email.de}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}



\setkomavar{subject}{Dies hier ist ein Blindtext zum Testen von Textausgaben.
}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{letter}{Richard M Winsor\\
2192 Lawman Avenue\\ 
Arlington\\
22204 Virginia
}
%
\opening{Dear Mr Winsor,}
%
\blindtext[1]
\noindent \blindtext[4]


\closing{\raggedright Yours sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

will result in

[image]

I think, this would be enough text for the first page. If you want more use either option `DIV` or use package `geometry` to increase the type area.

Comment: What actually decides whether a option is set at `\documentclass` area or in the *.lco `\KOMAoptions` area?

Comment: @Hölderlin Set options before the result of the option is needed by other packages. The font size influences the paragraph skip and indent. All three may be used so set other length, e.g. pseudo lengths of `lco` files or lengths of other packages. So these options should be set as early as possible or you have to e.g. recalculate the typing area and reload `lco` files to get the same result. Late change of the font sizes is almost ever and incomplete change. See also the notes above `fontsize` in the manual.