# How To Align Addresses Of Sender And Receiver In scrlttr2 Or scrletter

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2, scrletter

Assume that I want to write a letter with KOMAscript (either via `\usepackage{scrlttr2}` or `\usepackage{scrartcl} \usepackage{scrletter}`) and I want to store the address of the sender in the location field, more precisely, in the corresponding KOMA variable like in the following:

```
% Alternative 1
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

% % Alternative 2
% \documentclass{scrartcl}
% \usepackage{scrletter}

% Text body
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% Aligns the address field to the top
\KOMAoption{addrfield}{topaligned}

% % Toggle for the backaddress
% \KOMAoption{backaddress}{false}

% KOMAvars
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Sauron, Barad-dûr, Mordor}
\setkomavar{signature}{Sauron}

% Inserts sender into the location field
\setkomavar{location}{%
    % skip by <magiclength>
    \raggedleft Sauron\\Barad-dûr\\Mordor
}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Saruman\\Orthanc\\Isengard}

    \opening{Dear Saruman,}

    \kant[1]

    \closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

The relevant portion of the output sheet is the upper part:

[image: Output Upper Part]

How can I accomplish to align both addresses as if would write (forgive me)

```
Saruman \hfill Sauron\\Orthanc \hfill Barad-dûr\\Isengard \hfill Mordor
```

in normal text, regardless of the presence of a backaddress (and in the best case, regardless of the presence of a so called special mail hint).

A naïve solution attempt would possibly find the right pseudolength (as indicated by `% skip by <magiclength>` in `\setkomavar{location}{[...]}` but I cannot find such a length (compare with the graphic in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109855)).