# KOMA-Script (scrartcl+scrletter): Adjust spacing of signature with "\includegraphics{..}" from closing

Tags: graphics, koma-script, letters

It seems that the KOMA package `scrletter` (used with the class `scrartcl`) ensures that there is vertical space between the output of the `\closing{..}` and where the KOMA variable `signature` is used and this "extra" space is added even if a signature is added via e.g. `\includegraphics{signature}`; How can I get rid of this space in this case?:

[image: Included signature with large vertical space between it and the closing beforehand]

The code which produced the above is:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
% Package import declarations
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Include graphics for LaTeX

% Document settings
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{585px-Abraham_Lincoln_1862_signature}\\Abraham Lincoln}
%\setkomavar{signature}{Abraham Lincoln}

\setkomavar{subject}{Application for candidacy for the Republican primaries}


\begin{letter}{Illinois Republican Party\\
Chicago Office\\
P.O.\ Box 64897 \\
Chicago, IL 60664}

\opening{To whom it may concern:}

I would hereby like to propose myself as a presidential candidate for the Republican Party because I love freedom and bald eagles and I hate slavery and stuff like that.

\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the pseudolength `sigbeforevskip` (default is `2\baselineskip`) to your needs.

Example:

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
% Package import declarations
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Include graphics for LaTeX

\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

% Document settings
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=\baselineskip]{example-image-A}\\Max Mustermann}
%\setkomavar{signature}{Abraham Lincoln}

\setkomavar{subject}{Application for candidacy for the Republican primaries}


\begin{letter}{Illinois Republican Party\\
Chicago Office\\
P.O.\ Box 64897 \\
Chicago, IL 60664}

\opening{To whom it may concern:}

I would hereby like to propose myself as a presidential candidate for the Republican Party because I love freedom and bald eagles and I hate slavery and stuff like that.

\closing{Yours sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

Meanwhile (since version [3.26.2980](https://komascript.de/release3.26), ~ since 2019) there is the "userspace"-command `\setplength` so that it reduces to:

```
\setplength{sigbeforevskip}{.5\baselineskip}
```